# Looping jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have small animation made with jQuery (panels goes up and comes down). But I am not able to make it a loop. So it would do it continuesly. Here's the code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    startAni();   

});

function startAni() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ani .panels').animate({
            top: '-350px',
        }, 2500, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.ani .panels').animate({
                    top: '0px',
                }, 2500, function() {
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }, 1000);


    //startAni();
}
```

So it works perfectly once (the panels div goes up, stays there for 1sec and then comes back down. How can I change this in to loop? I tried calling the same function inside the function but that just killed it :/

Thanks!

Comment: Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works:

http://jsbin.com/esaraj/4/edit#javascript,html,live

```
  function startAni() {
            $('.ani .panels').animate
            (
            {top: '250px'}, 2500, function(){
setTimeout(   
              function() {                                                            $('.ani .panels').animate
(
{top: '0px'}, 2500, function() 
{
startAni();
}
);},2500);});}


          $(function()
  {

    startAni();   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var time = 1000; //time between loops
$(document).ready(function() {

    var interval = setInterval('startAni()',time);   

});
```

Comment: This doesnt do anything... hmm. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: you are includiing the function startAni(), right? can you provide any link?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `setInterval` and rewrite your function like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //interval = 2500ms + 2500ms = sum of all animation steps
   var interval = 5000;
   var looping = setInterval(startAni, interval); 
   startAni(); //starts animation right away
});

function startAni() {
     $('.ani .panels').animate({
            top: '-350px',
        }, 2500, function() {
            $('.ani .panels').animate({
                top: '0px',
            }, 2500);
        }
    });
}
```

the changes in original func were not mentioned in prev answers so I decided to write a separate one

UPD: if you have more than one item in `".ani .panels"` you should instead go with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //interval = 2500ms + 2500ms = sum of all animation steps
   var interval = 5000;
   var looping = setInterval(startAni, interval);  
   startAni(); 
});

function startAni() {

    var animating = false;
    $('.ani .panels').animate({
            top: '+50px',
        }, 2500, function() {
             // the callback tries to run for every item in '.ani .panels'
             // we need it to run only once
             if(!animating){
                animating = true;
                $('.ani .panels').animate({
                   top: '0px',
               }, 2500, function() { 
                  // reset flag for a single callback instance invocation
                  animating=false; 
               });
           }
       }
   );
```

}

[the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akoptsov/4kVFa/)

Comment: These works almost, but the panels should stop for a sec in top and bottom. Hence the timeouts on my original.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Automatic loop function with html code. I hope this may be useful for someone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
position: relative;
background-color: #abc;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button id="go">Run »</button></p>
<div class="block"></div>
<script>

function test() {
$(".block").animate({left: "+=50", opacity: 1}, 500 );
   setTimeout(mycode, 2000);
};
$( "#go" ).click(function(){
test();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sBxWH/)**